# How to prove that $\neg (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land q) \equiv \neg p \lor q$?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

This is what i got so far:

(~pvq) v (q∧~p)  ≡

I like using association property, but it's not possible in this case, because of (q**∧**~p), if I use Morgan's law on this part, this is what will happen

(~pvq) v ~(~qvp) ≡

But I do not know if we can do Distributive in this case since theres a negation mark.

How do i do this? I have to finish this ASAP. Help me please.

Comment: yeah, but i can't use truth tables

Comment: What deduction rules are you using? I am assuming you cannot use truth tables since you are trying to prove the statement *syntactically*, as opposed to *semantically*...

Comment: I formatted the title. Please use it to format the question. If you don't show some effort, not even in formatting, I suspect the moderators will close (and perhaps delete) your question soon.

Answer (score 3):

A short version of the solution looks for example like this:

\begin{align}\neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) &\equiv \ (\neg \ p \ \lor q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \\ &\equiv \ ((\neg \ p \ \lor q) \lor \neg \ p) \ \land ((\neg \ p \ \lor q) \lor \ q) \\ &\equiv \ (\neg \ p \ \lor q) \ \land (\neg \ p \ \lor  \ q) \\ &\equiv \ \neg \ p \ \lor q \  \end{align}

---

A lengthy version for the above mentioned short version of the solution looks for example like this:

First some theoretical background on boolean algebra. In boolean algebra there are two distributive laws and they read as follows for 3 boolean variables $x, y$ and $z$:

1. $\color{blue}{x \ \land} \ ( y \ \lor \ z) \ \equiv \ (\color{blue}{x \ \land} \ y) \lor  (\color{blue}{x \ \land} \ z) $
2. $\color{red}{x \ \lor} \ ( y \ \land \ z) \ \equiv \ (\color{red}{x \ \lor} \ y) \land(\color{red}{x \ \lor} \ z) $

Note: In each distributive law, the boolean variable $x$ is distributed with whatever operation next to it. These laws can be proven for example with a truth table.

---

There are also two so called De Morgan's laws, which read as follows:

1. $ \neg \ ( y \ \lor \ z) \ \equiv \ (\neg \ y) \ \land \ (\neg \ z)  $
2. $ \neg \ ( y \ \land \ z) \ \equiv \ (\neg \ y) \ \lor\ (\neg \ z)  $

Note: The Operations exchange and the negation operates on the individual variables. This law is also valid for more than two variables. These laws can be proven for example with a truth table.

---

Also, the double negation of a variable $\neg \ \neg \ p $ is the variable $ p $ itself (double negation rule).

---

There are also associative laws for both operations $\land$ and $\lor$ and some other laws like idempotent laws, commutative laws etc. which you should be able to check, for example here: https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm

---

A proof for the **statement**:

$$\neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \ \equiv \ \neg \ p \ \lor \ q$$

---

could look like this: The first expression $\neg \ (p \ \land \neg \ q)$ can be simplified with the help of the 2nd de Morgan law as mentioned above and the double negation rule to be $\neg \ p \ \lor \ q \ $, so $$\color{red}{\neg \ (p \ \land \neg \ q)} \ \equiv \ (\neg \ p) \ \lor (\neg \ \neg \ q)\ \ \equiv \ \neg \ p \ \lor q\ . $$ If we substitute $ \color{red}{x} \ \equiv \ \neg \ p \ \lor \ q \ $, then the left side of the **statement** $$ \neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \ $$ becomes $$ x \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \ . $$

Using the 2nd distributive law as mentioned above: $$ x \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \ \equiv \  (x \ \lor \ (\neg \ p)) \land (x \ \lor \ q) \ . $$

Plugging back $ \ \neg \ p \ \lor \ q \ \ \equiv \ x$ in this last expression, we get

$$  ((\neg \ p \ \lor \ q ) \ \lor \ (\neg \ p)) \land ((\neg \ p \ \lor \ q ) \ \lor \ q) \  $$

According to the associative law of the $\lor$-operation we can drop the brackets and get:

$$  (\neg \ p \ \lor \ q  \ \lor \ \neg \ p) \land (\neg \ p \ \lor \ q  \ \lor \ q) \  $$

Changing the positions of $ \ \neg \ p$ and $ q $ inside the left bracket (Commutative law of the $\lor$-operation) of the above expression, we get:

$$  (\neg \ p  \ \lor \ \neg \ p \ \lor \ q ) \land (\neg \ p \ \lor \ q  \ \lor \ q) \  $$

According to the idempotent law of the $\lor$-operation, we get $\neg \ p  \ \lor \ \neg \ p \ \equiv \neg \ p $ and $ \ q  \ \lor \ q \ \equiv \ q$, the above expression becomes

$$  (\neg \ p  \ \lor \ q ) \land (\neg \ p \ \lor \ q  ) \  $$

We can substitute $y \ \equiv \ \neg \ p  \ \lor \ q $ and the above expression becomes

$$  y \land y \  $$

According to the idempotent law of the $\land$-operation the above expression becomes

$$  y $$

Substituting back $  \neg \ p  \ \lor \ q \ \equiv \  y $ the left side of the statement becomes

$$  \neg \ p  \ \lor \ q   $$

the right side of the statement.

---

Another short version of the solution looks for example like this:

\begin{align}\neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) &\equiv \ (\neg \ p \ \lor q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) &&(l_1)
\\ &\equiv \neg \ p \ \lor q \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) &&(l_2)
\\ &\equiv \neg \ p \ \lor \ (q \ \land \ 1) \ \lor (q \ \land \ \neg \ p) &&(l_3)
\\ &\equiv \neg \ p \ \lor \ q \ \land \ (1 \ \lor \neg \ p) &&(l_4)
\\ &\equiv \neg \ p \ \lor \ q \ \land \ 1 &&(l_5)
\\ &\equiv \neg \ p \ \lor \ q \    &&(l_6) \end{align}

Tip: Read old texts on boolean algebra, which are free to find on the internet for example here: archive.org. In some old texts the operation "$\lor$" is called "$+$", the operation "$\land$" is called "$\cdot$" and the negation $\neg \ q$ is called $\overline{q}$. So, the same problem could also read like this: $ \overline{p \cdot \overline{q}} + \overline{p} \cdot q \ \equiv \ \overline{p}+q $ and the solution like this:

$$\begin{align}(\overline{p \cdot \overline{q}}) + (\overline{p} \cdot q) & \equiv (\overline{p}+q)+(\overline{p}\cdot q) &&(l'_1)
\\ & \equiv  \overline{p}+q+(\overline{p}\cdot q) &&(l'_2)
\\ & \equiv  \overline{p}+(q\cdot 1)+(q \cdot \overline{p}) &&(l'_3)
\\ & \equiv  \overline{p}+q\cdot (1 + \overline{p}) &&(l'_4)
\\ & \equiv  \overline{p}+q\cdot 1 &&(l'_5)
\\ & \equiv  \overline{p}  + q &&(l'_6)\end{align}  $$

As in arithmetic multiplication of variables, sometimes the "$\cdot$" is ommited, e. g. $p \cdot q \equiv pq$.

---

Some hints to the above solution:

1. In the first line $(l_1)$ or $(l'_1)$, which is the same, only De Morgan's law for the OR-operation is used on the expressions $\neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q)$ or $\overline{p \cdot \overline{q}}$, which are the same thing, to get $\neg \ p \ \lor q$ or $\overline{p}+q$, which again are equal things, respectively.
2. In the second line we use the associative law for the OR-operation or in other words, we neglect the brackets. Here we could also neglect the brackets around the variables joined by the AND-operation, because in boolean algebra: the AND-operation has precedence over the OR-operation, like for example multiplication has precedence over addition in arithmetics (precedence rules)
3. In the third line we substitute for $q$ the expression $q \land 1$. It's just the same thing by the definition of the AND-operation. If $q = 0$, then $q \land 1 \equiv 0 \land 1 \equiv 0 \equiv q$ and if $q \equiv 1$, then $q \land 1 \equiv 1 \land 1 \equiv 1 \equiv q$. Now $q$ is a boolean variable and can only be either $0$ or $1$. So whatever $q$ might be, it is always $q \land 1 \equiv q$.
4. In the fourth line the distributive law of the AND-operation is used in the reverse direction.
5. To get from the fourth line to the fifth line, we use the fact that $1 \lor x \equiv 1$ regardless of what $x$ might be. This can be verified by plugging $0$ and $1$ for $x$ and checking the results as in point 3.
6. In general there are 4 rules for the operation of boolean variables, e. g. $x$, with boolean constants, these are the constants $0$ and $1$. The rules are: $x \land 1 \equiv x$, $x \land 0 \equiv 0$, $x \lor 1 \equiv 1$, $x \lor 0 \equiv x$.

---

You might would like to try finding a way of forming the right hand side $\neg \ p \ \lor \ q$ into the left handside $ \neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \lor (\neg \ p \ \land \ q) \ $ to get a third possible solution, maybe like this:

\begin{align}
\neg \ p \ \lor q &\equiv \ ((\neg \ p) \ \lor q) \ \land ((\neg \ q) \ \lor  \ q) 
\\ &\equiv  \ (((\neg \ p) \ \lor q) \ \land (\neg \ q)) \ \lor  \ (((\neg \ p) \ \lor q) \ \land ( \ q))
\\ &\equiv  \ ((\neg \ p)\land (\neg \ q)) \ \lor (q \land (\neg \ q)) \  \ \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) \ \lor \ (q \ \land  \ q) 
\\ &\equiv  \ ((\neg \ p)\land (\neg \ q)) \  \lor  \ 0 \ \lor \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) \ \lor \ q
\\ &\equiv  \ ((\neg \ p)\land (\neg \ q)) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) \ \lor \ q
\\ &\equiv  q \ \lor \ ((\neg \ p)\land (\neg \ q)) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) 
\\ &\equiv  (q \ \lor \ (\neg \ p)) \land (q \ \lor \ (\neg \ q)) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) 
\\ &\equiv  (q \ \lor \ (\neg \ p)) \land 1 \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q)
\\ &\equiv  (q \ \lor \ (\neg \ p)) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q)  
\\ &\equiv  \neg \ ((\neg q) \ \land \ p) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q)  
\\ &\equiv  \neg \ (p \ \land \ (\neg q)) \  \lor  \ ((\neg \ p) \land  \ q) 
\\ &\equiv  \neg \ (p \ \land \ \neg \ q) \  \lor  \ (\neg \ p \land  \ q) 
\end{align}

using many different rules of boolean algebra and the fact that $(\neg \ q) \lor \ q \equiv 1$ regardless of the value of $q$ and also the fact that $x \land 1 \equiv x \lor 0 \equiv x$ regardless of the value of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply distribute $(\neg p \lor q)$ into $q \land \neg p$:

\begin{align}(\neg p \lor q) \lor (\neg p \land q) &\equiv (\neg p \lor q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg p \lor q \lor q) \\&\equiv (\neg p \lor q)\land (\neg p \lor q) \\&\equiv (\neg p \lor q)\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Via Boolean algebra,

$$\overline{ p \bar{q} } + \bar{p} q = \bar{p} + q + \bar{p} q = \bar{p} + \underbrace{(1 + \bar{p})}_{=1} q = \color{blue}{\bar{p} + q}$$

Answer (score 1):

Via Boolean form, we have
$$\neg\left ( p\land\neg q \right )\lor\left ( \neg p\land q \right )\quad\equiv\quad p\Rightarrow q\quad\equiv\quad\neg p\lor q$$